# Which sample type is more proper for whole genome sequencing in AML patients? Peripheral blood or bone marrow?

Tags: genetics, cancer, dna-sequencing

I intend to perform whole genome sequencing in AML patients in order to find genomic abnormalities, particularly translocation and gene fusions. However, I am not sure whether it is better to obtain peripheral blood or bone marrow or if there is no significant preference between them.

Please, provide me with scientific resources to refer to.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). You also need to specify why you are doing this and what you mean by "proper". I would also guess that this is going to depend on many factors including what is already known about the patients and the resources available. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: In particular, note that bone marrow biopsies are painful and carry a non-trivial risk of infection (and other negative outcomes) for the patient. Consequently, I double any responsible institution is going to let you get that kind of sample unless you can come up with a compelling reason for doing so (from the perspective of the patients).

Comment: Thank you immensely for taking your time and guidance. Regards